# Specify indexPath.row for a new item in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an iOS project I'm working on using Xcode7 and Swift. The user can add items to an `Array` called "details" that is viewed in a `TableView`. Is there a way to specify the location of where you want the new item to be?  Let's say I have 5 items in my array and I want the next added item to be placed in location `indexPath.row` for position 3. How do I do that? How can I make the new `details[indexPath.row]` be 3 for that item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the item into the "details" array at a specific index, then reload the table view.

```
details.insert("This String", atIndex: 3)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I was unaware of the `.insert' feature.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `details` is:

```
var details = ["Hello", "Hi", "Bye", "Goodbye", "No"]
```

Wherever you want to add the next item (I'm assuming position 3 means the 3rd index):

```
details.insert("Hey", atIndex: 3)
```

Then reload the table view:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the item in `details` at the requested index and call `tableView.reloadData()`or `tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` passing the same index wrapped in `[NSIndexPath]`. But first check if the index is not out of bounds.